# Генератор отчетов у которого (у отчета) есть конвертируемый показатель

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода, полиморфизм, шаблон-стратегия

Есть в базе таблица с результатами тестов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как и обычно по навигационным свойствам осуществляется доступ к другой информации, к такой как *фамилия*, *имя*, *название теста* и *т.д*.

При создании модели отчета для **некоторых** тестов необходимо значение поля `Grade5` конвертировать в строковой эквивалент. Например:

> 2 => "Уровень ниже базового"
>
> 3 => "Базовый уровень"

или

> 2 => "Не зачет"
>
> 5 => "Зачет"

Для разных тестов по разному и необходимо обеспечить эту гибкость при создании фабрики отчетов.

Много поигравшийся с паттерном *Стратегия* и *Фабричный метод* в итоге я наколдовал вот это:

```
public abstract class ParticipReport
{
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ParticipReportWithGrade : ParticipReport
{
    public int Grade5 { get; set; }
}

public class ParticipReportWithLevel : ParticipReport
{
    public string Level { get; set; }
}

public interface IParticipReportMaker
{        
    ParticipReport Create(int id, Dictionary<int, string> dict = null);
}

public class ParticipReportMaker : IParticipReportMaker
{
    private MyDbConxtex _db = new MyDbConxtex();

    public ParticipReport Create(int id, Dictionary<int, string> dict = null)
    {
        var result = _db.TestResult.Find(x => x.Id);

        if (dict == null)
        {
            var gradeReport = new ParticipReportWithGrade();                
            gradeReport.Surname = result. ...Surname; //доступ к Surname по навигационным свойствам
            gradeReport.Name = result. ...Name;

            return gradeReport;
        }

        var levelReport = new ParticipReportWithLevel();
        levelReport.Surname = result. ...Surname;
        levelReport.Name = result. ...Name;            
        levelReport.Level = dict[result.Grade5];

        return levelReport;            
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var levels = new Dictionary<int, string>
        {
            { 2, "Ниже базового" },
            { 3, "Базовый" }
        };
        var maker = new ParticipReportMaker();

        var report = maker.Create(1, levels);
    }
}
```

---

### Разбор полетов

Я в продакшен этот код еще не пустил, но думаю работать он будет.

Две вещи в этом коде мне не нравятся с ходу:

1. Идет дублирование кода при инициализации полей `Surname` и `Name` в модели отчета.
2. В клиентском коде каждый раз приходится передавать словарь `levels`в метод `maker.Create()`. Хотелось бы как-то правильно инициализировать объект `maker`. Ведь за раз я будут обрабатывать только один тип тестов (с конвертацией или без конвертацией `Grade5`).

---

### Вопрос

На сколько дела хороши в выше приведенном коде и правильно ли реализован полиморфизм если нет возможности менять структуру БД?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Инициализацию `Surname` и `Name` можно передавать в конструкторы
   классов, а те в свою очередь будут это передавать в свой базовый
   класс. Получится, что инициализация будет только в 1 месте.
2. А почему бы словарь не хранить в БД? Тогда не придется перекомпилировать программу, если что-то поменяется. Я думаю, что должно быть какое-то место, где бы все это хранилось. Хотя бы в XML рядом с программой, если нельзя менять структуру БД. Тогда не придется каждый передавать данные в метод, а класс их будет сам автоматически подтягивать из хранилища.
   После этого бы завел `enum`, который будет содержать типы отчетов и вместо уже ненужного dict передавал бы его и логику в форме сменил с `if` на `switch`, что сделает код чуть красивее=> если появится новый тип, то его будет легче добавить.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к хранению информации в базе. Разработчик должен писать код, а не перекомпилировать по десять раз на дню захардкоженные константы в приложении. Создать роль на редактирование справочников и отдать операторам -- пусть сами вводят. А если у вас приложение нужно в разные компании поставить, вы начнёте выносить это тут же -- не в БД, так в app.config

Comment: Помимо `Surname` и `Name` у меня еще 8 свойств, итого: 10 общих свойств - одинаково инициализируемых для семейства отчетов. Разве эта хорошая практика передачи такого количества параметров в конструктор класса?

Comment: @adamshakhabov заведи структуру какую-нибудь.

Comment: @iluxa1810 без примера кода мне трудно понять. Но тем не менее, правильно ли я понимаю, что 1) в методе `Create` будет создана `структура`, 2) будет получен результат: `var result = _db.TestResult.Find(x => x.Id)`, 3) свойства `структуры` будут инициализированны объектом `result`, 4) и затем `структура` будет передаваться в конструктор `ParticipReportWithGrade()` или `ParticipReportWithLevel()` **?**

Comment: @adamshakhabov ну как-то так. Структура- это классический способ избавиться от передачи большого числа параметров. Можно в методе Create ее объявить как object, что бы не плодить методы Create, а потом в зависимости от enum она будет пробрасываться в нужный конструктор типа, а там приводится к нужному типу.